# image overlay of grayscale image with color image

Tags: image, matlab, overlay

In Matlab, `Imoverlay` can create an overlay of a gray scale image with a binary image.  Is it possible to create an overlay of a gray scale image with a color image (*i.e.* same thing, but with intensity information mapped into the overlay with a colormap such as `jet` - the overlay would vary from red to blue based on its intensity)?

It seems that this can be done with `imfuse`, but not clear on how to specify one image as gray scale and the other as color scale.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Are you talking Matlab?

Comment: Which framework or OS are you using?

Comment: Matlab has no native `imoverlay` function, but there are several on the file exchange. Which one are you talking about? [This one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42904-imoverlay) says that it will plot color on grayscale. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.  I was using a different version which didn't allow input of the colormap.  Thanks!